# git and heroku integration

Tags: git, heroku

I am deploying my app to heroku and it works, But i dont understand one thing. So i have my sample express application stored in github repository. but then in Heroku deoloyment documentation there is a command `git push heroku master`

Does it mean that Heroku takes my app and crates another version of my app in their github...? really confused and if so can i see this repo..?

ps. I have been going through this documentation but there isynt really a explanation on how this actually is linked and weorks:

Comment: "Does it mean that Heroku takes my app and crates another version of my app in their github...?"—Heroku doesn't "have a github". Well, [they do](https://github.com/heroku/), but it's for their own code, not for users' code. **Git and GitHub are different things, and one can use Git without GitHub.** When you `git push heroku` this has nothing whatsoever to do with GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two remote, one on github (that you may have called origin), and one on heroku that is called.. heroku. When you push to the heroku remote it then trigger a pipeline to make your application available from the master branch (you push master on heroku).

Hope it helps.

EDIT: to clarify, yes you are pushing to a private git repository that is only used to "make" your application and deploy it. I don't know if then you can retrieves what's on it, depending on the policies they have on it.